# Is this the correct way to use pointer,or I have to use smart pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers

How could I check whether a pointer's content is deleted? If I use QPointer like this:

```
myClass::myClass(myStruct* p){
 _p = p;//_p is a myStruct*
}

myClass::function(){
if(_p) {_p->function();}
}
```

then I have

```
myStruct* p = new myStruct();
myClass A(p);
delete p;
p = NULL;
A.function();
```

will the last A.function() cuase the _p->function() be called and therefore cause access violation? when I delete p, what will happen to _p?

Comment: Avoid smart pointers at all costs. Use regular C style pointers always.

Comment: What? **DON'T** avoid smart pointers

Comment: @self Keep that advice to self...

Comment: @self that's just as bad as "Avoid C style pointers at all costs. Use smart pointers always."

Comment: I see five separate questions here. "Will ... cause access violation?" -> Yes (hopefully). "When I delete p, what will happen to _p?" -> Nothing. "How could I check whether a pointer's content is deleted?" -> You can't. "Do I have to use smart pointers?" -> No. "Is this the correct way to use pointers?" -> If you didn't delete the object, it would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are implementing shallow copy that means `delete p` would make your struct member `_p` dangling.

You can implement deep copy like:-

```
myClass::myClass(myStruct* p)
{
  //Allocate memory for _p.
  //copy all data from p to _p.
}
```

Comment: So a deep copy will solve the problem? Could you kindly show me a short example?

Comment: Making a copy means `p` and `_p` are no longer *related*, so changes in the outside pointer won't affect the member pointer. If that's not desirable, smart pointers are a good option.

Comment: But why I see many people suggest to never use smart pointers? Is it self buggy?

Answer (score 0):

Using smart pointers in this context (properly) would actually cause a compiler error if you tried to do what you did above and it was invalid. For instance, if you knew that there should only be one owner of the struct at any one time, use a unique_ptr:

```
myClass::myClass(std::unique_ptr<myStruct>& p)
{
   _p = p;//_p is a std::unique_ptr<myStruct>
}
```

then:

```
std::unique_ptr<MyStruct> p(new MyStruct());

MyClass a(p); // <-- compiler error, cannot copy a unique_ptr, only move it
```

Note, that you do not have to worry about `delete`ing your struct, as the smart pointer handles it (as soon as the unique_ptr goes out of scope).

If, however, you wanted to share ownership of your struct, you could use a shared_ptr and copy it fine. Then, again, you would never need to delete it manually, because it will automatically delete its self when all objects no longer reference it.

```
myClass::myClass(std::shared_ptr<myStruct>& p)
{
   _p = p;//_p is a std::shared_ptr<myStruct>
}
```

then:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyStruct> p(new MyStruct());

MyClass a(p); // <-- no compiler error, works OK

// no need to call delete! but if you wanted to no longer use `p` anymore, simply do:
p.reset(); // <-- now MyClass is the only owner of MyStruct.
```